# Dynamic Page Based On Dropdown Selection

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic, drop-down-menu

I am working on a sign up system. There are different prices for different membership types. Associate is $25,  Family is $40, Regular is $35, Regular Family $40, Honary is $0, and Institutional is $25. I need a dropdown menu that will change the Amount Due based on the membership selected.

My Code Right Now:

```
<p>Current Status: 
<select name="status_current">
<option value="">Please Select</option>
<option value="A">Associate</option>
    <option value="F">Family</option>
<option value="R">Regular</option>
<option value="RF">Regular Family</option>
<option value="H">Honary</option>
<option value="I">Institutional</option>
</select>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, include jQuery in your page, just like this:

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

I would then use jQuery like this:

> $('#dropDownId').val();

Or To get the currently selected text:

> $('#dropDownId :selected').text();

I would then make a function that is runned when the user changes the option.

```
<p>Current Status: <select id="dropDownId" name="status_current" onchange=YourFunction()> 
<option value="">Please Select</option> <option value="A">Associate</option>
<option value="F">Family</option> <option value="R">Regular</option>
<option value="RF">Regular Family</option> <option
value="H">Honary</option> <option value="I">Institutional</option>
</select></p>
```

Then your Javascript function could be something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function YourFunction(){
    if($('#dropDownId').val()=="A"){
        $("#Div_to_show_the_price").html("25$");
    }
    else if($('#dropDownId').val()=="F"){
        $("#Div_to_show_the_price").html("40$");
    }
}
</script>
<div id="Div_to_show_the_price"></div>
```

And so on with the other options.

Comment: I'm kind of a noob at javascript, how would you display the result of the javascript?

Comment: It's already displaying the result with that part: $("#Div_to_show_the_price").html("40$"); -----it will put "40$" in the div with the ID: #Div_to_show_the_price

Comment: It's not working for me. Is there any way to do it, like with document.write?

Comment: I edited my answer to explain you how to include jQuery in your page. Please if it works, put my answer as useful. Thanks and I hope I could help you

Comment: you have two <head> in your code on the link you provided me. Just keep the first <head> and the last </head>

Comment: I did that, and now the form works, but the price still doesn't display.

Comment: At this point it's basic Html/Javascript...you did not give the ID's to your select menu and you didn't have the div with the Div_to_show_the_price ID. you can call those any way you want. Please check at my answer edit.

Comment: Please dont! But I'd suggest you reading a bit on the basics of jQuery, it would probably be very useful to you in the future. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to ues javascript or preferably jQuery as php is a server side process.
For dynamic pages you must please the client side.

jQuery is a really easy thing to get into so get into it. Here's the code in jquery

```
    //when select triggers change, and if family is selected 
    //change the price display
    //or do something else, whatever you want 
$("#my-select').on('change',function(){
    if($(this).val() == "Family")
        $("#price-display").html('35');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<p>Current Status:
    <select id="dropdown" name="status_current" onchange="CheckVal();">
        <option value="">Please Select</option>
        <option value="A">Associate</option>
        <option value="F">Family</option>
        <option value="R">Regular</option>
        <option value="RF">Regular Family</option>
        <option value="H">Honary</option>
        <option value="I">Institutional</option>
    </select>
</p>
<div id="show"></div>
```

JS:

```
function CheckVal() {
    var val = $('#dropdown').val();
    if (val == "A") {
        $("#show").html("25$");
    } else if (val == "F") {
        $("#show").html("40$");
    }
    else if (val == "R") {
        $("#show").html("35$");
    }
    else if (val == "RF") {
        $("#show").html("40$");
    }
    else if (val == "H") {
        $("#show").html("0$");
    }
    else if (val == "I") {
        $("#show").html("25$");
    }
}
```

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/TZL3p/

Answer (score 0):

You may add an attribute to `option` that can contain the amount.

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/TZL3p/1/

Comment: What attribute would that be exactly?

Comment: You can use your own attribute. in my example i used "amount"